# Convert Angular component.html file into a normal name.html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a lot of Angular components which contains mostly html and css. Those components are actually designed slides. Now I want to get rid of Angular, because I want to use HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Is there a fast way to convert all those components into HTML, CSS and Javascript files? It mainly concerns the transfer from Angular to HTML.

Let me know (:

I have only try to search for a answer, but I didn't find a fasted way to do this.